# PHP with MYSQL data flow

Tags: php, mysql, database, browser

I'm using php with mysql.

I have a large database of `mysql` containing 365 tables, each day contain a single table and that contains thousand of records for each client in single table.
My problem is that when I'm going to generate the report for multiple clients it doesn't show any thing.

On other hand when I check `mysql` log it shows queries running on back end, when queries a completed at back end still nothing comes to browser, browser still show process running.

My current code looks like this:

```
//$ClientList Contains 100 clientIds
//$TableList contains 30 table list
$TotalCount = count($ClientList);
$CountTables = count($TableList);
for($i=0; $i<$TotalCount; $i++) {
    for($j=0; $j<$CountTables; $j++) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO TABLEA SELECT * FROM ".$TableList[$j]." WHERE clientid = '".$ClientList[$i]."'";
        $rs = mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
for($i=0; $i<$TotalCount; $i++) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLEA";
    //STORE IN ARRAY
    $rs = mysql_query($sql);
    while($ds=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
        $aRRAY[$i] = $ds;
    }
}

for($i=0; $i<count($aRRAY); $i++) {
}
```

But nothing is coming to browser I have also added the `settimeout` to 0; increased session time, but no results. Any solution to this issuee?

Comment: it's rare to have 1 day per table. Why not having 1 table having a date field instead ?

Comment: Your code is not printing/echoing anything out to the page.

Comment: do you output anything in this loop? for($i=0; $i<count($aRRAY); $i++) {
}

Comment: Also, your tables could be better optimised, instead of 1 table per day, why not have a field for date/time in your main table and a seperate table for clients, so that it is a normalised design. You can do lookups and searching by datetime then.

Comment: What do you do on years with a leap day?

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions for database access.  They're deprecated in all but name and aren't up to date for dealing with MySQL5 databases.  Use a more modern interface such as mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Does the browser "hang", as in does it continuously keep trying to load etc?

If so, you may need to up the max execution time, or use AJAX.

Comment: Adder I am having 1.5 Millions records/day

Comment: @user1749938 I think the real question here is *why* you have 1.5 million records a day - do you really need all of them? Do you have any unique columns that the DB needs to check through when inserting new values, that could result in it being slow?

Comment: What does 1.5m records per day have to do with anything? A properly configured database can handle that in one table. Denormalizing the database structure is not necessarily a solution.

Comment: What about selecting from only one table (for example the very first day of the year)? Does it return results fast or still hangs somewhere? And when you mentioned you are doing some kind of report with the data, I am pretty sure, you aren't just printing 1.5M of records. If you are using some summing, average counting, etc., you should do that in database. It would be cool if you could provide us with a little bit more of information so we can help more.

Comment: when im selecting only one table it is fine, but when im going to query more then seven days with the use of union all then it takes time some times it gets results and some times i get some thing like that remote server reset the connection...

Comment: and i have primary key on tableid and clientid

Answer (score 0):

Do not store one million records in a php array:

```
//$ClientList Contains 100 clientIds
//$TableList contains 30 table list
$TotalCount = count($ClientList);
$CountTables = count($TableList);
for($i=0; $i<$TotalCount; $i++) {
for($j=0; $j<$CountTables; $j++) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO TABLEA SELECT * FROM ".$TableList[$j]." WHERE clientid = '".$ClientList[$i]."'";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
}
}

//OUTPUT
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLEA";
//
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
while($ds=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    my_output($ds);
}
```

Also if you are trusting the database to put all your records into TABLEA, why put them into separate tables at all?

```
//$ClientList Contains 100 clientIds
//$TableList contains 30 table list
$TotalCount = count($ClientList);
$CountTables = count($TableList);
for($i=0; $i<$TotalCount; $i++) {
    for($j=0; $j<$CountTables; $j++) {
        //OUTPUT
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$TableList[$j]." WHERE clientid = '".$ClientList[$i]."'";
        //
        $rs = mysql_query($sql);
        while($ds=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
            my_output($ds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have three date fields in my daily table, the daily table is transactional table, in which clients data are stored. i have 8 thousand clients, and every second there are hundred of insertions.